# Entity Framework , Работа с моделью данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня в базу данных заливается множество таблиц с одинаковой схемой , например

f170101 , f170102 , т.е каждый день появляются новые. Вопрос такой, как в Entity Framework Можно подменять имя таблицы выполняя .ToList() чтобы данные подгружались из определенной таблицы

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<ORMAdisCalls>().ToTable(TableName, schema: "statistica_call");
}
```

Как динамически возможно сделать такую подмену , в запущенной программе всегда возвращаются данные с той таблицы , которая была передана методу выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать разные контексты для выполнения операций над таблицами.

Создадим контекст, в конструктор которого будем передавать наименование таблицы.
Поскольку контекст кэширует DataModel, нам потребуется придумать свой механизм определения ключа, по которому будет выполняться кэширование модели.
Для этого создается класс [DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model) :

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string tableName)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
    }

    public string TableName { get; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<ORMAdisCalls>().ToTable(TableName, schema: "statistica_call");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory>();
    }
}

public class DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context is MyDbContext dynamicContext)
        {
            return (context.GetType(), dynamicContext.TableName);
        }

        return context.GetType();
    }
}
```

Добавим метод, который создает экземпляр контекста и возвращает нужные нам данные:

```
List<ORMAdisCalls> GetORMAdisCalls(string tableName)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext(tableName))
    {
        return context.Set<ORMAdisCalls>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Получим содержимое из разных таблиц в одну и ту же модель:

```
void Foo()
{
    var table1Calls = GetORMAdisCalls("f170101");
    var table2Calls = GetORMAdisCalls("f170102");
}
```